# Slider with curved path

Tags: ios, swift, slider

[image]I need to create custom slider which path is curved. See the image above.

I can get the x position of the path, but how can I get its y position for each x point?

Comment: This is far too broad of a question. Please review [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is that you can define a [quadratic Bézier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B%C3%A9zier_curves) for that curve, e.g., with a little utility function, `point(at:)` to tell you for values between 0 and 1, where the point is on that Bézier:

```
struct QuadBezier {
    var point1: CGPoint
    var point2: CGPoint
    var controlPoint: CGPoint

    var path: UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: point1)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point2, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        return path
    }

    func point(at t: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let t1 = 1 - t
        return CGPoint(
            x: t1 * t1 * point1.x + 2 * t * t1 * controlPoint.x + t * t * point2.x,
            y: t1 * t1 * point1.y + 2 * t * t1 * controlPoint.y + t * t * point2.y
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can then use that to define the curved path:

```
let bounds = view.bounds
let point1 = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY)
let controlPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY + 100)

let bezier = QuadBezier(point1: point1, point2: point2, controlPoint: controlPoint)
```

And you can then set the `center` of your circular view accordingly:

```
circleView.center = bezier.point(at: t)
```

E.g., here I’ve used `path` computed property to render blue `CAShapeLayer`, and using `point(at:)` to set the `center` of the red circular view based upon a value `t`:

[image]

Obviously, I’m using a gesture to scrub changes of `t`, but you can use your custom stepper or whatever to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for @rob your help. And please answer to one more question if you can:
What is "t" parameter when you are setting circleView.center = bezier.point(at: t) and how you drag that circle with pan gesture or how?

Comment: It’s just a value that ranges from zero (the first point) to one (the second point) along the path defined by quad Bézier with the specified control point. (We use `t` as a matter of convention because Bézier curves often represent movement within the “time” domain.)

Comment: And please can you provide full code you use for this answer?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/67484c74297cede3926a3aed2fceedb9